# ffmpeg matches no streams Stream specifier '' in filtergraph description

Tags: ffmpeg

```html
ffmpeg -y -i a.mp4 -i b.mp3 -filter_complex '[0]volume=1,atrim=start=0:end=5,adelay=0|0[aud0];[1]volume=1,atrim=start=0:end=5.796,adelay=0|0[aud1];[aud0][aud1]amix=2' mergeAudio.mp3
```

a.mp4 only video stream!

how to repair the code

[image: 1]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Gyan merge all audio of media，but some video not has audio stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, use the `anullsrc` filter to generate a silent stream and use that in `amix`.

`ffmpeg -y -i a.mp4 -i b.mp3 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -filter_complex '[2]volume=1,atrim=start=0:end=5,adelay=0|0[aud0];[1]volume=1,atrim=start=0:end=5.796,adelay=0|0[aud1];[aud0][aud1]amix=2' mergeAudio.mp3`